# Select all from MySql and join other

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this codeigniter function

```
function allClients($orderby = 'clients_company_name', $sort = 'ASC')
{

    //profiling::
    $this->debug_methods_trail[] = __function__;

    //declare
    $conditional_sql = '';

    //check if any specifi ordering was passed
    if (! $this->db->field_exists($orderby, 'clients')) {
        $orderby = 'clients_company_name';
    }

    //check if sorting type was passed
    $sort = ($sort == 'asc' || $sort == 'desc') ? $sort : 'ASC';

    //----------sql & benchmarking start----------
    $this->benchmark->mark('code_start');

    //_____SQL QUERY_______
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *
                                      FROM clients
                                      ORDER BY $orderby $sort");

    $results = $query->result_array(); //multi row array

    //benchmark/debug
    $this->benchmark->mark('code_end');
    $execution_time = $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('code_start', 'code_end');

    //debugging data
    $this->__debugging(__line__, __function__, $execution_time, __class__, $results);
    //----------sql & benchmarking end----------

    //return results
    return $results;

}
```

It selects all data from table clients. One of them is "client_team_profile_id" - the owner of this client.

I also need to join other table - team profiles. There we can find team_profile_id (there are ids of users in system) and team_profile_full_name - names of users.

```
Table: clients

clients_id|clients-company_name|client_address|clients_team_profile_id
1         |Apple               |some street   |2
2         |Dell                |some street   |5


Table team_profile

team_profile_id | team_profile_full_name|
2               |John                   |
5               |Bob                    |
```

I need to select all data from table CLIENTS (as we can see - Select *) and also get name of team user connected to client and set a parameter for result - AS f.ex. client_owner_name.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well if _Making a JOIN it is not a very big problem_ and as your query is in plain text, just add the JOIN to your existing query

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this, are you able to give useful help?

Comment: Not unless you show the actual table definitions of all the tables you want to query data from. Your description is unclear, and that just leads to guesses on my behalf and then you say that does not work and we go round and round

Comment: Sure, I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can add this JOIN to your existing query

```
SELECT c.*, t.team_profile_full_name as client_owner_name
FROM clients c
    JOIN team_profile t ON t.team_profile_id = c.clients_team_profile_id
ORDER BY $orderby $sort"
```

You may also need to change this bit of code to use the table alias like so

```
 //check if any specifi ordering was passed
if (! $this->db->field_exists($orderby, 'clients')) {
    $orderby = 'c.clients_company_name';
}
```

And also

```
function allClients($orderby = 'c.clients_company_name', $sort = 'ASC')
```